# mysql error referring to Null

Tags: mysql

```
$sql1= "CREATE TABLE bookapp(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30),
pnumber int(11),
emailID VARCHAR(50),
reg_date datetime()
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)";
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''', NULL)' at line 1

Comment: Put , after reg_date datetime()

Comment: Are you sure this is the query that produced this error? In the error message MySQL reports the part of the query that it didn't understand (or where it found an error). Your query **does not** contain `'', NULL)`.

Answer (score 4):

**You can use the following to create the table:**

```
CREATE TABLE bookapp(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    pnumber INT(11),
    emailID VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

**Explanation:**

- `(` and `)` on `DATETIME` is invalid. `DATETIME` doesn't need a length.
- You have to seperate the column definitions with `,`. You forgot this after column `reg_date`.

**Hint (to your error message):**

Your given `CREATE TABLE` throws another error message, that is different to yours:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') PRIMARY KEY(id) )' at line 6

Comment: Please identify what you changed and why.

Comment: This answer seems to solve the SQL errors in the posted code. However, the error message generated by MySQL for the posted query is not the one posted in the question.